# How to manage CloudFoundry / Micro Cloud Database

Tags: cloud-foundry

Hello I am just thinking how to actually manage the database MongoDB or MySQL inside the Cloud Foundry? Can we get the port to which to connect to and use the standard management tools like phpMyAdmin etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `vmc tunnel` to create an https tunnel from your local machine to the remote Cloud Foundry service:

http://start.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html

Assuming you have phpMyAdmin installed locally, you can point it to 127.0.0.1, port 10000, and supply the database name, username, and password given from the output of `vmc tunnel`.